# Spark took 20G + memory to write a 140MB Parquet file

Tags: java, apache-spark, memory-management, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I have a spark job which is read in a smaller parquet file and make some changes to column names then repartition it into slightly larger file and sort with in partition.

Eventually write to HDFS in parquet format.

But based on YARN container log:

2018-10-10 20:51:19,397 INFO 
 org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 13331 for container-id container: 26.9 GB of 35.5 GB physical memory used; 35.0 GB of 74.5 GB virtual memory used

Where the file is only 145MB in size

Here is the code:

```
df.repartition(32, columns)
            .sortWithinPartitions(columns)
            .write().parquet(PATH)
```

each task of this job is taking 25GB+ physical memory usage

Comment: Interesting observation, but what is your question? Please be specific about what you're asking. Also, add details on how you submitted the spark job. How much memory did you give the driver and the executors?

Comment: I give 32GB for each executors. My questions, what is taking up so much memory giving that the data size is relatively small

Comment: @LunjieJin did you find any workaround or solution to this issue? Thanks in advance!